# Trying to display Usernames of my Users from FirebaseStorage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display my users username from firebase, however this line of code:

```
self.userNameOut.text! = DataSnapshot.value!["username"] as? String
```

returns an error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type
```

does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit:
I think my connection to the database is wrong..

`````
var loggedInUser = AnyObject?.none
var databaseRef = DatabaseReference()
var storageRef = StorageReference()````

        self.loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

    self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let userDict = snapshot.valueInExportFormat() as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                print(userDict["username"] as! String )
                self.userNameOut.text =  userDict["username"] as? String ?? ""
            }
        }
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to get `username`, I hope it helps you.

```
if snapshot.exists() {
     if let userDict = snapshot.valueInExportFormat() as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
          print(userDict["username"] as? String )
          self.userNameOut.text =  userDict["username"] as? String ?? ""
     }
} else {
    //Data not found
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help as always @AtulParmar ! would you have any idea on how to connect it to a ui label? in specific im trying to connect to ````@IBOutlet weak var userNameOut: UILabel!````

Comment: See updated answer, just assign text to your userNameOut UILabel

Comment: Thanks Atul for all of your help! I think my connection to the database is wrong? if you dont mind can you see any errors in my connection? (see edit above)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `DataSnapshot.value` but assuming the value is not `nil` you can access it like this as `Firebase Database` uses a `JSON` tree format (key/value pairing) this means you need to type cast `snapshot.value` to a `dictionary`:

```
if let fbDictionary = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {  
    let username = fbDictionary["username"] as! String 
} else {
    print("Error retrieving data, value nil?") 
}
```

Usually you would like either to [listen to changes in the Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) or you would like to [fetch one specific user knowing its ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once). In both cases, once you have the firebase datasnapshot that is valid you can access a field in it like `username` by accessing it as a Dictionary like the above example.